After installing the "TenancyForLaravel" package, my routes point to the root directory and not the "public" directory
I have a problem that has been difficult for me to solve. I installed the "TenancyForLaravel" package in which all routes coming from the "central domains" are processed separately from those coming from the "subdomains". Since I am in a local environment, my routes always pointed to "http://localhost/myproject/public/", however, after installing the mentioned package, all the links now point to "http://localhost/". I know this is related to the controllers or middlewares that were installed with that package, but I don't know how to solve it. I appreciate any help! Thank you.
foreach (config('tenancy.central_domains') as $domain) {
    Route::domain($domain)->group(function () {

        // my routes

    });
}

